# ndk-build ignoring source with errors

Tags: android-ndk, compiler-warnings

I'm new to c/c++ and NDK but i can't seem to find what i would have thought to be a well known question/answer. Does the following error on running `ndk-build` mean that the following set of files haven't been compiled:

```
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in /cygdrive/d/opt/workspace/ProjectName/jni/Android.mk for module ModuleName
Android NDK:   CRC32.c, MD5.c, File2.c, File3.c
```

Or, is that a list of files which have successfully compiled?

EDIT::

I can confirm after trial and error that those files /are/ being ignored. The delimiter you need to use in the Android.mk file is a single space " " character, not  comma space characters ", ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should format Android.mk files to compile like below:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES+= CRC32.c MD5.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES+= ForkProcess.cpp
```

That is, `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` can be formatted like this for a single list of files to compile:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= CRC32.c MD5.c
```

Or, if you wish to seperate the list of compiled files (Perhaps there is a logical non modular structure in the source files), as above you can use `+=`.

Errors in this variable declaration can give the error in the question.